# Line quality issues in GIMP

Tags: gimp, pixel, line-art, krita

I'm currently testing out GIMP and Krita; so far I find GIMP more feature-rich but I also have some quality concerns when it comes to the lines that GIMP draws. And I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

For example these are circles drawn in GIMP, the inner one with a paintbrush stroke and the outer one with regular line stroke:

(notice the strange edge algorithm even though the circle is perfectly symmetrical)

[image]

And these are the same circles drawn in Krita:

(They look much more professional and Photoshop-like)

[image]

I'd like to keep using GIMP over Krita but if there is no way to improve the line quality then I'll have to switch. Any tips?

Comment: Did you stroke selections or paths?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Selections, how would you make a circle with a path?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Ok, I found an option to make a selection into a path and then stroke the path instead of the selection, this is definitely a much better result. Although I'm not sure if it's still as good as Krita.

Comment: Yes, stroking paths gives much cleaner results than stroking selections. If you need to create paths with geometric shapes  try the [ofn-path-to-shape plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/)

Comment: I placed the plugin in the plugins folder and I can't see anything in the interface. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of playing around I managed to get the quality of the circle in GIMP up to par with Krita.

This does however add a few extra steps to the process. (I'd like to hear if someone knows a quicker way)

1. Make a regular `ellipse selection` (hold `shift` for perfect circle)
2. Click on `selection to path` in the path tab while holding `shift` for more options (this option creates a path out of the selected perimeter)

[image]

3. You will be presented with a path menu, change `filter iteration count` to maximum for best results.

[image]

4. Now that the path is created, select the `paint along the path` option and select the type of line you want.

[image]

This is the result, a nice smooth circle:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer you will also get on e.g. the #gimp IRC channel on irc.gimp.org. We'd love to see this be made easier, and there is even code to start from - a Google Summer of Code project for adding vector layers: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557970. Could be a nice project for GIMP 3.0.

Comment: BTW,  that advanced settings dialog started out as an April Fool's joke.